# Trigger a subtree Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, mutation-observers

How can I trigger a subtree change with MutationObserver?

### JavaScript

```
function mutate(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        console.log(mutation.type);
    });
}

var target = document.querySelector('div#mainContainer');
var observer = new MutationObserver( mutate );
var config = { attributes: true, characterData: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

observer.observe(target, config);
```

### HTML

```
<div id="mainContainer">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Paragraph.</p>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7HT5.jpg" alt="Photo" id="photo" height="100">
</div>
```

I can trigger an attribute change with:

```
document.getElementById('photo').src = 'http://i.imgur.com/Xw6htaT.jpg';
```

I can trigger a characterData change with:

```
document.querySelector('div#mainContainer p').innerHTML = 'Some other text.';
```

I can trigger a childList change with:

```
jQuery('div#mainContainer').append('<div class="insertedDiv">New <div>!</div>');
```

How is a subtree change triggered so console.log(mutation.type); prints it out?

Comment: `subtree` means the mutations are reported for any nested node inside the target, it's not a separate type of mutations.

Comment: Cool, thanks wOxxOm.

Comment: [MutationObserver documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).